# React MUI theme defaultProps cause unknown prop warnings

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-props

I added these to my MUI Theme, and the UI looks great.

[image]

The issue is that I'm getting this warning.
[image]

We have already figured out how to cease such warnings using shouldForwardProp but it's not working with defaultProps:
[image]

Thanks, Itay.

Comment: disableElevation is a property of MuiButtonBase not MuiButtonBase. have you tried to move it to MuiButton in theme?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I’m not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move properties to button in `createTheme`

```
components: {
        MuiButton: {
            defaultProps: {
                disableElevation: true,
                disableFocusRipple: true,
            },
        },
        MuiButtonBase: {
            defaultProps: {
                disableRipple: true,
            },
        },
    },
```